# Asterisk AMI for sip message

Tags: node.js, asterisk, sip

I'm running an Asterisk PBX with a nodejs module for listening to AMI events. One thing I'm trying to capture is sip messages. Watching the asterisk client I'm able to see the message and content but when listening to AMI events I do not see the message coming across. Is there a configuration that needs to be enabled to see sip messages via AMI events (similar to 'sip set debug on' in the asterisk client) or is there another way I would need to listen for SIP messages?

Comment: I'm guessing I could use something like adding a custom UserEvent to the dialplan.   https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Application_UserEvent

Answer (score 1):

No sir. There are no way see channel-level messages via any way except set sip debug on(channel will dump to console).

There are 2 possible variants

1) patch console or grab info from console, put into other "ami-like" channel for your need

2) grab info from network itself using libpcap/tcpdump.